# "Опять за рыбу деньги"

Tags: фразеология

Часто слышу такую поговорку. А откуда она вообще пошла?

Comment: Честно говоря, в таком варианте поговорка мне никогда не встречалась. Говорят: "Опять за рыбу - грОши", с ударением на "О", что показывает украинское происхождение выражения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, это не совсем поговорка.
Упоминается у Катаева в "Белеет парус одинокий". Не помню, в тексте или только в экранизации. Там по сюжету торговка обсчитывает Гаврика, принесшего ей рыбу на продажу.

Comment: А что значит слово, не по-русски написанное?

Comment: Оно значит, что писавший по своему обюыкновению куда-то очень спешил - и даже не посмотрел, чего пишет. У меня это бывает. Простите. И - спасибо, конечно.

Comment: Во многих словарях пословиц и поговорок это выражение присутствует. Жаль, что ответ помечен как принятый — это может вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: @grizzly А в чем, простите, заблуждение?

Comment: В вопросе спрашивается, откуда она пошла. Вы отвечаете, что либо Катаев придумал, либо сценаристы сочинили. Это, конечно, не так, поэтому вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: @grizzly  Я не отвечаю такого. Хотя по большому счету и не исключаю. А у вас есть основание полагать, что Катаев тут что-то сплагиатил?

Comment: Да, согласен, что Ваш ответ читается неоднозначно. Я привёл основную трактовку. Ещё вариант: Вы хотели сказать, что выражение получило известность благодаря Катаеву. Можно придумать и другие варианты понимания ответа — от этого он не становится лучше. Далее. Вы серьёзно полагаете, что упоминание в художественной литературе народных пословиц и поговорок считается плагиатом?!